# Can I update two TextView separately using MVVM?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have two different TextView in a layout, and I am bringing information from the repository, through the ViewModel.

My idea is to separately bring each content and put each one in its TextView. But what happens is that the two TextViews are filled with the data from the last call to the ViewModel.

### Layout

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPrivacy"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.DisplayBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
             />

        <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:dividerInsetStart="16dp"
            app:dividerInsetEnd="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTerms"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.DisplayBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
```

### Fragment

```
    final TextView textPrivacy = binding.textPrivacy;
    final TextView textTerms = binding.textTerms;

    mViewModel.getText(FILE_PRIVACY).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textPrivacy.setText(Utils.fromHtml(s),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    });


    mViewModel.getText(FILE_TERMS).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textTerms.setText(Utils.fromHtml(s),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    });
```

### ViewModel

```
public LiveData<String> getText(String rawPath) {
    return mRepository.getText(rawPath);
}
```

### Repository

```
public class FileRepository {
    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    @Inject
    public FileRepository() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText(String rawPath) {
        try {
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(rawPath);
            byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(b);
            mText.setValue(new String(b));
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mText.setValue( String.format("Error: <br>%s",e.getMessage()));
        }
        return mText;
    }

    // ...

}
```

In this scenario, both `textPrivacy` and `textTerms` take the content of `FILE_TERMS`, which is the last call to the ViewModel.

Why does `textPrivacy` change its value, if I am not changing it on the second call?

What is the best way to achieve what I want: **update both TextView separately**?

Comment: What is the `getText()` method in your view model. How and where are you setting the value of your LiveData?

Comment: @FilipPetrovski I added ViewModel and Repository code...

Comment: In the end, you are observing the same LiveData twice, the value of mText.

Comment: Problem is that you observing mText in both TextViews. You need a LiveData for each TextView in this scenario

Comment: Both observers will be triggered simultaneously whenever there is a change in the LiveData; and therefore both TextViews will have the same data

Comment: @FilipPetrovski Ok. I understand now. My idea is to use `FileRepository` to read multiple files from different contexts. Only in this Fragment I need to read two files at the same time. What would be the best way to do it? Creating another method in `FileRepository`?

Comment: Remove `private MutableLiveData<String> mText;`, return a new LiveData from your func

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment.
You are observing the same LiveData twice. Your method returns mText both times so both your textViews will get the same data.
First they will be filled from the result of `getText(FILE_PRIVACY)`, then the data will be overwritten by `getText(FILE_TERMS)`

To solve that issue you will need 2 separate methods in your repository, `getTerms()` and `getPrivacy()`, which is a better design anyway. It is more clear and understandable.

Your view model will call those 2 methods and your activity will observe the data changes on them, giving you 2 independent values.